# Does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{1+\frac{1}{k}}\frac{\arctan{(3+\pi k)}}{\sqrt{k^4+2k-\sin{(k)}}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{1+\frac{1}{k}}\frac{\arctan{(3+\pi k)}}{\sqrt{k^4+2k-\sin{(k)}}}$ converge?

I can't come up with any good methods to solve this.

Both D'Alembert's and Cauchy's criterions answer is 1 so it can't be solved in this way. It might be solved using Abel's theorem but I can't find any solutions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define, for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_k := k^{1+\frac{1}{k}}\frac{\arctan(3+\pi k)}{\sqrt{k^4+2k-\sin(k)}}$ and observe that, as $k\to+\infty$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\arctan(3+\pi k ) &\sim \frac{\pi}{2}, \\
\sqrt{k^4+2k-\sin(k)} &\sim k^2, \\
 k^{1+1/k} = k  e^{1/k \log (k) } &\sim k.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore $a_k \sim \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{k}{k^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{k}$. Since $a_k \geq 0$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and since the series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ diverges, we conclude that $\sum_1^\infty a_k$ diverges by the Limit Comparison Test.